# Pandas: The best way to create new Frame by specific criteria

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
              'sex': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]})
    id  sex
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   2   0
7   3   1
8   3   1
9   3   0
10  4   1
11  4   1
```

I want to get new DateFrame where there are only id's with both sex values.
So I want to get something like this.

```
    id  sex
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
4   3   1
5   3   1
6   3   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `filter` with required condition

```
In [2952]: df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: set(x.sex) == set([0,1]))
Out[2952]:
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    0
3   1    1
7   3    1
8   3    1
9   3    0
```

Also,

```
In [2953]: df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: all([any(x.sex == v) for v in [0,1]]))
Out[2953]:
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    0
3   1    1
7   3    1
8   3    1
9   3    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by both columns and then get size of one column by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) first.

Then filter all values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = df.drop_duplicates()['id'].value_counts()
print (s)
3    2
1    2
4    1
2    1
Name: id, dtype: int64

df = df[df['id'].isin(s.index[s == 2])]
print (df)
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    0
3   1    1
7   3    1
8   3    1
9   3    0
```

Answer (score 2):

One more:)

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['sex'].nunique()>1)

    id  sex
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
7   3   1
8   3   1
9   3   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isin()

Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
              'sex': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]})

male = df[df['sex'] == 0]
male = male['id']
female = df[df['sex'] == 1]
female = female['id']

df = df[(df['id'].isin(male)) & (df['id'].isin(female))]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    0
3   1    1
7   3    1
8   3    1
9   3    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this

```
m=df.groupby('id')['sex'].nunique().eq(2)

df.loc[df.id.isin(m[m].index)]


Out[112]: 
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    0
3   1    1
7   3    1
8   3    1
9   3    0
```