# Choose between two values and set the most frequent in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201618/pandas-the-best-way-to-create-new-frame-by-specific-criteria) recently, but now I have a new problem. Here is my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
              'sex': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]})

    id  sex
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   2   0
7   3   1
8   3   1
9   3   0
10  4   1
11  4   1
```

Now I need to set sex value for id's with mixed sex values. It should be the most frequent value. So i want to get something like this:

```
    id  sex
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   2   0
7   3   1
8   3   1
9   3   1
10  4   1
11  4   1
```

And after that I want to get only one id - sex pair:

```
id  sex
0   1   0
1   2   0
2   3   1
3   4   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `np.bincount` as well.

```
In [179]: df.groupby('id')['sex'].apply(lambda x: np.argmax(np.bincount(x))).reset_index()
Out[179]:
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   2    0
2   3    1
3   4    1
```

Timings

```
In [194]: df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

In [195]: df.shape
Out[195]: (12000, 2)

In [196]: %timeit df.groupby('id')['sex'].apply(lambda x: np.argmax(np.bincount(x))).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop

In [197]: %timeit df.groupby('id')['sex'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop

In [198]: %timeit df.set_index('id').groupby(level=0).sex.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.71 ms per loop
```

Comment: I thought about using this... but I wasn't doing it right, so gave up. Thanks for showing me the right way.

Comment: If you're benchmarking, can you benchmark my option 2 as well? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnGalt - i think it is a bit problematic for timings in groups - there use only huge small amount of groups. Better is df with more catagories.

Comment: @jezrael -- Good point, I agree, please do if you can. However, I'd bet bincount to be fast for most reasonable cases.

Comment: Seems like it'd be simpler (maybe not faster) to just use the `mode()` method: `df.groupby(by=['id']).apply(lambda x: x.mode()).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @PaulH -- quite true.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You can use `groupby` followed by `value_counts` and `idxmax`.

```
df = df.set_index('id').groupby(level=0).sex\
          .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()).reset_index()
df

   id  sex
0   1    0
1   2    0
2   3    1
3   4    1
```

---

**Option 2**
Similar to *Option 1*, but in 2 steps, using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sex = df.groupby('id').sex.transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
df

    id  sex
0    1    0
1    1    0
2    1    0
3    1    0
4    2    0
5    2    0
6    2    0
7    3    1
8    3    1
9    3    1
10   4    1
11   4    1

df = df.drop_duplicates()
df

    id  sex
0    1    0
4    2    0
7    3    1
10   4    1
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful.

Comment: @Renton Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) which sorting by default, so only first index is necesary selected by `[0]`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['sex'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  sex
0   1    0
1   2    0
2   3    1
3   4    1
```